# Dynamically Add Field to Model Form Using Django

Tags: python, html, django

I have a model that has fields for an address such as Street, City, State, Zip. I have created a form that allows the user to input values for each of these. What I would like to do now is make it where the user can press a button, say "add address" and then each field would be repeated. I could use jquery to add fields to the HTML, My issue is how would these extra fields need to be represented in the model?

Ultimately, I'd like to take the additional addresses and use them in a search where I retrieve anything that has any of the addresses the user has input. Any help or suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: You are looking for django dynamic formset .. here is the link : https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset

Comment: Thank you, I will check it out. I have seen dynamically adding form fields but I don't want to add the entire form, just some fields from the form. I will look at the link and let you know if it's what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Vijay! I couldn't mark yours as the answer (not sure why) but your link helped me.

Since I only wanted some fields to repeat, I put only those fields in the table.

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="">
{% for form in formset.forms %}
    <p> {{ form.nonDuplicatingField }}
    <p> {{ fomr.anotherNonDuplicatingField }}
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>{{ form.duplicatingField }}</td>
               <td>{{ form.duplicatingFieldTwo }}</td>
               <td>{{ form.duplicatingFieldThree }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
{% endfor %}
{{ formset.management_form }}
</form>
```

And I included this javascript (in addition to jquery and jquery.formset)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#myForm tbody tr').formset();
    })
</script>
```